# I Keep Finding layers Stacked in each other

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

Im building this character. When I click a vert and move it turn out there's another vert in that area with the same facing. I keep finding these throughout the model and I have no idea how im causing them.

The image below is verts where stacked on each other.

[image]

Comment: you've somehow duplicated your mesh, try first to remove doubles, in 2.7: W > Remove Doubles, and play with the merge distance on the bottom of the left panel

Comment: Thank you ! your the best :)

Comment: you also could have tried L to select the separate meshes  ;)